# Environmental sealing of buzzers

Tags: piezo-buzzer, environmental-sealing

If you have a buzzer mounted in an enclosure and you want to let sound get out freely, but prevent ingress of dust and water, are there standard techniques or solutions to this common electronics design scenario? If I make a hole in the enclosure the buzzer is plenty loud. But putting anything over the hole greatly reduces the sound output.

There must be a way to allow the sound out while preventing ingress of contaminants. The application involves constant motion and varying orientations in an outdoor dirt or mud trail environment. Rain and splashes are possible and size is highly constrained.

Or worst case I will just get a louder buzzer.

The buzzer I am working with at the moment is this one:
CUI devices P/N: [CMI-9651S-SMT-TR](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/cmi-9651s-smt-tr.pdf)

Comment: What exactly is the environment for this? Do you expect it to be under water? In the rain? On a boat? What exactly? Your job is to keep dust and water from reaching the hole. And not by plugging up the hole. So you have to keep the hole away from dust and water. But doing that means knowing a lot about what exactly you are doing with this. If it is in a fixed position somewhere, then shelter it somehow. A bull-horn also shows you some techniques used to keep unwanted things from getting to the speaker. Learn from that design?

Comment: Arrange one face of the enclosure to be a resonant membrane and couple the transducer to that.

Comment: @jonk not underwater. Mobile, active outdoor trail type environment. So rain, mud and splashes are possible. I would not expect sound transmission to occur when it is caked with mud, but it should start working again once the mud is washed off.

Comment: @mkeith What about the ideas applied in designing bull-horns, though? Those are placed outside, up high and directed downward a little, and I've seen those devices work well for years and years outside. I literally live in a rainforest system, with 65 inches of rain a year, and of course plenty of mud. They just work. They are big, of course. But other than that, what about them doesn't work for you?

Comment: @user_1818839 that seems a good idea, but do you know how to actually do that? It seems that there is some good science for taut membrane resonances. So I am starting to read about that.

Comment: I will look more closely at bull-horns. But in my case, the orientation is not fixed and mud may splash into the opening. Orientation will change and the enclosure will be in constant motion for extended periods in a trail environment. @jonk

Comment: @mkeith Okay. So more like a hand-held "bull-horn?" Those also exist, though I never tore one apart to see if it is any different in design from the outdoor fixed-position ones. They look similar, but there may be important differences inside that I didn't know about. Perhaps get and tear apart a good quality outdoor, hand-held bull-horn speaker. I think there is a lot going on in a good design -- delivery of sound outward, while protection against the elements. It's a good question and if you learn something please let us all know! Update question with more info and I will +1 it.

Comment: @mkeith You obviously want to shield the hole from splashes. That's... well.... a shield. The shield should direct the splash away, while allowing the splash to retain much of its velocity after the impact so that it can continue along, past, and then away from the area of your hole, as well. You will need to similarly shield from back-splashing, too. That pretty much seems to sum up the basics for the shielding part. The rest is about propagating the sound away and forward from all this shielding. That bull-horn design is looking better to me. Though you may want a small, modified version.

Comment: @mkeith Also, I'm more an optics design type than audio, but the forward reflector should have specific mathematical shape to deflect the outgoing sound backwards towards the hind-reflector-backsplash shield, which itself needs to have another mathematical shape designed to re-direct oppositely the outgoing sound back in the forwards direction without much dispersion (unless you want that.) I see math in the design here. Not just "shield from mud" thinking. There are "foci" involved, I think.

Comment: I don't think I have the depth for any type of double reflector design. The buzzer is just one little feature and we are trying to make it be audible. without opening our enclosure to the elements.